# Print based on multiple selection criteria

Tags: unix

My file has 3 columns:

File (Coma separated):

```
RS1  , 5 , 100
RS2  , 6 , 120
RS3  , 5 , 140
RS4  , 5 , 160
RS5  , 5 , 180
RS6  , 5 , 200
RS7  , 5 , 220
RS8  , 7 , 240
RS9  , 5 , 260
RS10  , 5 , 280
```

First, I want to print records based on criteria (>6) for column 2. The resultant file (File1) should look like:

File1:

```
RS2 , 6 , 120
RS8 , 8 , 240
```

Second, I want to define a range based on each value in column 3 of File1. E.g. subtract and add 30 in first value of column#3 "120" (the range will be 90 to 150). Similarly, subtract and add 30 in second value of column#3 "240" (the range will be 210 to 270).

Third, on the basis of above ranges, I want to print records that fall in these ranges. The resultant File should look like:

```
RS1 , 5 , 100
RS2 , 6 , 120
RS3 , 5 , 140 
RS7 , 5 , 220
RS8 , 7 , 240
RS9  ,5 , 260
```

I have tried following command for first step:

```
awk '{if($2 > 6) print$0}' File
```

But I don't now how to make commands for next two steps.

Can any body help, please?